# Trie find/add function not working properly

Tags: c++, search, data-structures, tree, trie

I am trying to implement a search function for my trie tree data structure. I am confused on how to properly implement this, as I assume my logic seems correct right now...although I am still a beginner in this. If someone can take a look at my function, and suggest where to improve, that would be greatly appreciated. The main takes in large word files and then searches for words in it to test the function basically. Right now it returns false for a word that should be in the trie object.

**example error message**

```
Error: jean-pierre is not in the spellcheck and it should have been
```

**search function:**

```
//looks up the word in the SpellCheck object. If it is in the SpellCheck object,true is returned. 
//You can assume that the word will be all lower case.
bool lookup(const string& word) const {

    if (!root_) {
            return false;
    }

    Node* curr = root_;

    if (word[0] == '\0') {
            return curr->isTerminal_ == true;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
            int idx = curr->getIndex(word[i]);

            if (idx < 0 || idx >= 26){
                    return false;
            }
            // Search top level for node that
    // matches first character in key

            if (curr->children_[idx] == nullptr) {
                    return false;
            }
            curr = curr->children_[idx];

    }
    return curr->isTerminal_ == true;
}
```

**Node struct:**

```
struct Node {
            bool isTerminal_;
            char ch_;
            Node* children_[26];
            Node(char c = '\0') {
                    isTerminal_ = false;
                    ch_ = c;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                            children_[i] = nullptr;
                    }
            }
            //given lower case alphabetic charachters ch, returns 
            //the associated index 'a' --> 0, 'b' --> 1...'z' --> 25
            int getIndex(char ch) {
                    return ch - 'a';
            }
    };
    Node* root_;
```

Comment: your lookup method looks okay. please provide your insert function

Comment: the insert function was working properly when tested.

Comment: then debug your code with putting break-point.

Comment: @Kaidul Islam it actually may be the add

Comment: @Kaidul i will add now

Comment: @Kaidul i added it. it was working fine, then all of a sudden it just stopped the program randomly while adding, but works for about 10 times fine

Comment: @user7795742 Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? Since it is **the** tool to use, in these situations.

Comment: Looking at your error about word `jean-pierre`, and then at Node which only has 26 possible children that I think are supposed to be Latin letters - my only conclusion is that when it encounters a dash (`-`) in the word, it aborts on a `idx < 0 || idx >= 26`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple bugs in your implementation.

Your `addWord` function isn't correct.
This one should be better:

```
void addWord(const string& newWord, int currChar, Node* rt)
{
    //check if currChar index is still in newWord
    if (currChar < newWord.length()) {
        //find index of currChar
        char currLetter = newWord[currChar];
        int idx = rt->getIndex(currLetter);

        //if no letter at that index create a new node
        if (!rt->children_[idx])
            //make a new node
            rt->children_[idx] = new Node(currLetter);
        //continue to add
        addWord(newWord, currChar + 1, rt->children_[idx]);
    }
    else
        rt->isTerminal_ = true; //last char
}
```

The other bug you totally missed: `"jean-pierre"` contains non a-z characters :) and your getIndex will fail for any char that's not within `[a-z]` range.

The other points:

- do not hardcode values like `26`, because if you need to update your
  range from `[a-z]` code elsewhere will silently fail.
- use [assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) to check input assumptions.

Something like this:

```
int getIndex(char ch)
{
    assert(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z');
    return ch == '-' ? 26 : ch - 'a';
}
```